# Nginx-ingress - Wrong src client ip (X-Real-Ip)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

When using nginx-ingress in Kubernetes (installed via helm), the `X-Real-Ip` is not my real IP (not preserving the original client IP)

I've tried `externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"`, `use-proxy-protocol: "true"` as suggested, but it didn't help...

Comment: Can you post your ingress and service?

Comment: @Crou this is a well know issue with `nginx-ingress`

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us with more info, like the `service` you're using,

From a quick guess, Looks like you're applying the `externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"` on the wrong service,

I also previously applied it to my `NodePort` service instead of the **Nginx Service** and it didn't work

Please check the service with `LoadBalancer` type, it's usually named `nginx-nginx-ingress-controller`, a quick `kubectl get services --all-namespaces` can show you a list of all the services running.

**TLDL**

`Local` means that when the packet arrives to a pod, kube proxy will only distribute the load within the same node pods even though other pods in the same cluster are less loaded.

On the other hand, when setting `Cluster` value, the balancing takes into account not only the nodes but also the number of pods to distribute the requests, and to avoid imbalance, Kubernetes perform the balancing within the cluster.

https://medium.com/pablo-perez/k8s-externaltrafficpolicy-local-or-cluster-40b259a19404

https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/issues/57#issuecomment-277777686